# \Rightarrow with text above it

Tags: formatting, arrows, stacking-symbols

When using the command `\Rightarrow` is there any way to put text above it? I have tried `\overbrace` but is there a way to do it without this?

Answer (score 246):

The optional argument is for *under*:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

$\xrightarrow[\text{world}]{\text{hello}}$
$\xRightarrow[\text{world}]{\text{hello}}$

\bigskip    
$\xrightarrow[g(x)]{f(x)}$
$\xRightarrow[g(x)]{f(x)}$  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This produces italicised text, so perhaps one should use a `\text{}` inside the arguments for "regular" text?

Comment: sure, it depends on what you want: a math expression or text!

Answer (score 30):

Probably, you will need the amsmath package, and the commands `\overset` or `\xrightarrow`.

https://web.archive.org/web/20180705220556/http://www.stack.nl:80/~jwk/latex/examples/node6.html