# Double arrow and variable on top

Tags: arrows, superscripts

How to create a double arrow line with a variable on its top. Something like this.[image]

Comment: Related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103988/rightarrow-with-text-above-it

Answer (score 2):

Try package `mathtools`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

$\xleftrightarrow[\text{world}]{\text{hello}}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: instead `\xleftrightarrow...` according to op question should be `\xLeftrightarrow ...`

Comment: @Zarko Really? Doesn't double just mean (here) that there should be arrow heads on both sides?

Comment: @marmot, hm, you are probably right ... question is not very clear to me :-(

Comment: @Zarko, I agree the question is maybe unclear but I tried the closest match to the picture :)

Answer (score 1):

With `\overset`:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage[]{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$
  \overset{n_S^i}{\leftrightarrow}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]